# Actionbar tabs with listfragment example

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am looking for a very basic example of using the action bar tabs with listfragment. I can do each one separately but I don't know how to combine the two together. I have seen one example from commonsware but it's not really all that basic so I can't really follow it well. Can anyone help me out?